# Go back to view controller with cached data

Tags: swift, objective-c, uitableview, segue, viewcontroller

I'm building an app which has 4 screens, on the second screen the user will set time by date-picker on tableview.

There are few times to be set (depending on `array.count`).
On the third screen the user will set the location, and on the 4th screen user will see info from API and the time has been set by the user, also on tableview cells.

In case the user wants to change or update the time he set in one of the cells to different time, I need to be able to go back to the second view with all the input user added already remain, and the user can change only the cells they want to change, without adding all the time all over again.

When I'm using segue it creates a new 2nd vc and all the previous info erased.

Answer (score 1):

I thing you have to use delegate to propagate this information from whichever screen to which ever screen you want. In Order to achieve that you have to loose the segue.

https://medium.com/@nimjea/delegation-pattern-in-swift-4-2-f6aca61f4bf5

In this link Delegation pattern is explained very well. Please refer that.